A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-media-library'. > No signature of method: build_b80uxo2ho0rbxravgm8tgj3d4.android() is applicable
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'D:\project\wecare\node_modules\expo-media-library\android\build.gradle' line: 62

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-media-library'.



No signature of method: build_b80uxo2ho0rbxravgm8tgj3d4.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_b80uxo2ho0rbxravgm8tgj3d4$_run_closure2) values: [build_b80uxo2ho0rbxravgm8tgj3d4$_run_closure2@59e45210]


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.


com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 18s
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'D:\project\wecare\node_modules\expo-media-library\android\build.gradle' line: 62

What went wrong:
PS D:\project\wecare\android> ./gradlew clean


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'D:\project\wecare\android\build.gradle' line: 52

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'lph'.



Could not find method android() for arguments [build_6z05ybaydf5ywzktutjlmh4oo$_run_closure2$_closure10@422942cd] on project ':expo-media-library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 7s
can anyone suggest here?
